# Access the file manager on webmin

Tags: opensuse, webmin

Today, when I try to open the file manager on my webmin page, it shows me the error that your security settings have blocked an untrusted application from running.

I updated the java but I am getting the same error.

Please help me to find the solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Due to a change of the Java Runtime version 7u51 on loading the file manager an error displays, that the application is blocked by security settings. This can be avoided by adding the address of the Webmin to the Exception Site List in Java Control Panel.

Please proceed as follows:

Open the Java Control Panel in Systems|Java.
Select the tab "Security".
Click the "Edit Site List..." button.
Click the "Add" button in the "Exception Site List" dialog.
Enter the address of Webmin, e.g. „http://licensecentral.company.local:10000“.
Click the "OK" button.
Click the "Continue" button to accept the security warning.
Click the "OK" button to close "Java Control Panel".

Answer (score 3):

By default the latest versions seem to block the Webmin Java modules, usually because there is some problem with the certificate. You can change the security settings or, much much better, add the server(s) you manage with Webmin to the site exception list using the Java security settings in the Java control panel. On a home server just add https:// followed by the site ip addresss. For me it seems to work if you tack on the :10000 for the Webmin port at the end. You will still get all sorts of dire warnings of the impending apocalypse when you access the modules, but at least they will work.
Full details of the Java security settings can be found here:
http://www.java.com/en/download/help/jcp_security.xml

Answer (score 2):

Chrome 42 has disabled java feature by default now.

For now you can just go to the url below in chrome and enable the npapi and relaunch.

chrome://flags/#enable-npapi

Come September 2015, that option will disappear permanently.

http://www.theregister.co.uk/2015/04/14/google_java_chrome_42

Answer (score 1):

I found Chrome Version 42.0.2311.90 m still shows the "plugin not supported" message even after trying all of the above suggestions.  I did find however if I clicked on this link http://www.java.com/en/download/installed.jsp I was able to allow the security prompts again and then noticed with Alauddin's tip you have to click the "restart" button at the very bottom right hand corner after enabling

chrome://flags/#enable-npapi

The browser closed and restored with all my open tabs and the java app was working again after confirming a prompt.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I tried force quitting the browser, and clearing all cache and data, and restarting browser, to no avail. I solved it by doing this:

In Chrome, I right clicked on the tab bar, to get the menu below:

[image: task manager chrome]

I found and selected the process called `Plug-in: Java` and clicked the "End Process" button

[image: java plugin chrome task manager]

You'll notice in the browser an error occurs "Plug-in Shockwave Java" (or something like that), "Has Crashed" and a button that says, "Reload". Click that reload button to reload the plugin.

Now you will again be offered permissions by Java to run the program.

The problem occurred because you accidentally did not allow the page a chance to offer you to allow Java permissions so it can run the file manager.

Answer (score 0):

I got frustrated trying the various fixes to Java 8 breaking Webmin file manager.  An Oracle Java page informs that reverting back to the latest release of Java Version 7 can be a solution.  A warning on the same page advises against it, saying v7 will not be updated for security fixes, etc.

After uninstalling v8 and installing Java V7U79, file manager works well.  An alternative way to ease security concerns is to go into Java control panel and set security level to high or set advanced controls to 'Very High' security.  Then when you want to run file manager or other known app, change the security setting to 'High' or 'Medium' level.  File manager runs under high level in v7u79 with advanced levels set to their defaults.

A permanent fix would seem to require rewrite of the file manager.